# Set ItemDataBound handler of a dynamically created repeater

Tags: vb.net, events, data-binding, repeater

I am creating a repeater dynamically in code behind. I then want to execute the OnItemDataBound event when the DataBind() method is invoked, like this:

```
Dim Repeater1 As New Repeater()
Repeater1.DataSource = dataSource
Repeater1.OnItemDataBound = "Repeater1_OnItemDataBound"
Repeater1.DataBind()
```

The compiler tells me the function OnItemDataBound is not accessible in this context because it is 'Protected'

I'm creating a dynamic repeater because the number of columns it needs depends on the data in the data source.

How do I execute my ItemDataBound code for each item in the data source when the DataBind method is invoked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to add an event handler, then you need to use the [`AddHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) statement:

```
AddHandler r.ItemDataBound, AddressOf Repeater1_OnItemDataBound
```

Of course the method must be accessible, normally it is in the same class:

```
Protected Sub Repeater1_OnItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)
    ' ... '
End Sub
```

Comment: Except I needed to do this: AddHandler Repeater1.ItemDataBound, AddressOf Repeater1_OnItemDataBound